# AWS chalice local works but not chalice deploy

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, chalice

I am pretty new to coding and aws chalice. I tried writing a code that gets messages from trading-view and executes orders depending on the signals.
I tested the code locally and everything worked fine, but when I test the Rest API I get the following error:
***{"message":"Missing Authentication Token"}***
I set up my credentials via "aws configure" as explained here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-files.html
I also created a config.txt file in my aws folder and checked my settings via "aws configure get" and they were fine.
The index function in the beginning worked too, so there should be a problem within my code?
I changed some values and cut some functions and the strategy part out, but the code looks somewhat like this:

```
from chalice import Chalice
from datetime import datetime
from binance.client import Client
from binance.enums import *
import ccxt


exchange = ccxt.binance({
    'apiKey': 'KEY',
    'secret': 'SECRET',
    'enableRateLimit': True,
    'options': {
        'defaultType': 'future',
    },
})

def buy_order(quantity, symbol, order_type = ORDER_TYPE_MARKET,side=SIDE_BUY,recvWindow=5000):
try:
    print("sending order")
    order = client.futures_create_order(symbol = symbol, type = order_type, side = side, quantity = quantity,recvWindow=recvWindow)
    print(order)
except Exception as e:
    print("an exception occured - {}".format(e))
    return False

return True

app = Chalice(app_name='tradingview-webhook-alert')
indicator1 = "x"
indicator2 = "y"
TRADE_SYMBOL = "Test123"
in_position = False

def diff_time(time1, time2):
    fmt = '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'
    tstamp1 = datetime.strptime(time1, fmt)
    tstamp2 = datetime.strptime(time2, fmt)
    if tstamp1 > tstamp2:
        td = tstamp1 - tstamp2
    else:
        td = tstamp2 - tstamp1
    td_mins = int(round(td.total_seconds() / 60))
    return td_mins

@app.route('/test123', methods=['POST'])
def test123():
    global indicator1, indicator2
    request = app.current_request
    message = request.json_body
    indicator = message["indicator"]
    price = message["price"]
    value = message["value"]
    if indicator == "indicator1":
        indicator1 = value
    if indicator == "indicator2":
        indicator2 = value
    if in_position == False:
        if (indicator1 >123) & (indicator2 < 321):
            balance = exchange.fetch_free_balance()
            usd = float(balance['USDT'])
            TRADE_QUANTITY = (usd / price)*0.1
            order_succeeded = buy_order(TRADE_QUANTITY, TRADE_SYMBOL)
            if order_succeeded:
                in_position = True
return {"test": "123"}
```

I tested it locally with Insomnia and tried the Rest API link there and in my browser, both with the same error message. Is my testing method wrong or is it the code? But even then, why isn't the Rest API link working, when I include the index function from the beginning again? If I try the index function from the beginning, I get the ***{"message": "Internal server error"}*** .
This is probably a very very basic question but I couldn't find an answer online.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I am not pretty sure if that helps you because I don't really understand your question but:

You are using a `POST-request` which will not be executed by opening a URL.

Try something like `@app.route('/test123', methods=['POST', 'GET'])` so that if you just open the URL, it will execute a `GET-request`

Some more information:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp